# What are the guaranteed ways to go to heaven?

Tags: heaven

What are the various guaranteed ways to go to heaven ?
I think one of them is Kshatriya dying on battle field always go to heaven.

What are the other ways ?

Answer (score 4):

There are many many ways but one interesting way is there for the criminals too. If criminals get duly punished by the king (law or Government in today's circumstances) then they also go to heaven just like virtuous persons.

> Manu Smriti 8.318. But men who have committed crimes and have been
> punished by the king, go to heaven, being pure like those who
> performed meritorious deeds.

Comment: Don't think it will be the case if laws are in opposition of what is mentioned in Smritis

Comment: Yes .. Only if punishment is apt the criminal will get heaven but if laws are such that punishments are not sufficient then it won't happen @Carmensandiego

Comment: How about the case when laws are in violation of snritis. Let's say person A ends up hurting person B , but he was defending a cow from being slaughtered by person B. Saving cow is considered highly meritorious in our scriptures. But the current regime punishes person A . So will person A goto heaven because he was punished?

Comment: The verse applies when crime has been committed and after that the sinner got the sufficient punishment ... In the situation you've mentioned it needs to be found out whether that is at a sin or not .. if someone is punished for no reasons then this verse does not apply in that scenario @Carmensandiego